# How to append to an array in Elasticsearch using elasticsearch-py

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

Using the Official [ElasticSearch Python library](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py) ([Docs](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/))

I create an index:

```
doc = {
    "something": "123a",
    "somethingelse": "456b",
    "timestamp": datetime.now(),
    "history": []
}
es.index(index="someindex", doc_type="somedoctype", id="someid", body=doc)
```

I would like to append items to the history each time, instead of overriding them:

```
es.update(index="someindex", doc_type="somedoctype", id="someid",
          body={"doc": {
                "history": {
                    "123abc": "abc", "456def": "def", "timestamp": datetime.now()
                }
               }
          })
```

What do I have to change in the second code snippet to get it to append to the history array/list instead of overriding it each time?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [scripted updates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates) in elasticsearch. For appending to array try something like this:

```
es.update(index="someindex", doc_type="somedoctype", id="someid",
      body={
         "script" : {
             "source": "ctx._source.history.addAll(params.history)",
             "lang": "painless",
             "params" : {
                 "history" : ["item1","item2"]
             }
         }
      })
```

Comment: docs don't mention addAll, this really helped

Comment: @Mozart  What if the document is not present?. I want to create a document if it is not present and append to array if the document is present. Refer my exact question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74489322/elastic-search-adding-an-element-on-an-array